# Windows: recursively search for, and execute, batch file from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, vim

I have a project with nested folders.

I want to be able to recursively look up directories until a "build.bat" file is found, and execute it.

How can I do this from the command line? (i.e. not a batch file itself).

Background (Optional): Trying to leverage vim's compiler and makeprg settings to run a build file located somewhere in the project, and redirect output to quicktips.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a particular project root folder is `d:\Remote` and it's your current working directory. Then (copied & pasted from my command prompt window):

```
d:\Remote>for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s build.bat') do @echo "%~G"
"d:\Remote\bat\test\build.bat"
```

Then you could simply remove `@echo`...

If you are in another working directory:

```
d:\bat>for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s "d:\Remote\build.bat"') do @echo "%~G"
"d:\Remote\bat\test\build.bat"
```

**Note** there could be found more than one file; if `@echo` removed then all found ones will go to be executed:

```
d:\Remote>for /F "delims=" %G in ('dir /b /s cdn.bat') do @echo "%~G"
"d:\Remote\bat\cdn.bat"
"d:\Remote\bat\test\cdn.bat"
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)